# C# how to query dynamic json?

Tags: c#, json, linq, dynamic, json.net

If retrieve a JSON string for which the full schema is not known :

```json
{
    ... other stuff
    "data": [
        {
            "open": 110.05,
            "high": 112.0,
            "low": 110.0,
            "close": 111.78,
            "volume": 21745034.0,
            "symbol": "GOOG",
            "exchange": "XNAS",
            "date": "2022-09-09T00:00:00+0000",
            ... more fields
        },
        ... more data
```

Then deserialize into dynamic :

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(response);
```

How to query for specific symbols ?

This doesn't work :

```
var match = result["data"].Where(e => e.Value["symbol"].ToString() == "GOOG").FirstOrDefault();
```

Gives error :

> Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically
> dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or
> expression tree type.

Answer (score 3):

if you are using `System.Text.Json` you can use `JsonNode` as Follows :

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.Json.Nodes;



var jsonObject = JsonNode.Parse(response)!.AsObject();

var match = jsonObject["data"]?.AsArray().FirstOrDefault(e => e["symbol"]?.ToString() == "GOOG");

//access properties
string open = match?["open"]?.ToString();
```

with `Newtonsoft` you can use `JObject` as Follows :

```
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;


var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(response);

var match = jsonObject["data"].FirstOrDefault(e => e["symbol"]?.ToString() == "GOOG");

//access properties
string open = match?["open"]?.ToString();
```